# SQL Server view with group by displaying all columns and rows with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-view

I have a table `Table` in SQL Server 2017 as follows. `start` is INTEGER. All of the other columns are NVARCHAR(255).

```
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+  
| operation | rule_set |  stem  | category | pattern  | start |  
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+  
| op1       | set1     | stem1  | cat1     | pattern1 | 100   |  
| op1       | set1     | stem1  | cat1     | pattern2 | 100   |  
| op1       | set1     | stem1  | cat2     | pattern3 | 150   |  
| op1       | set1     | stem2  | cat3     | pattern2 | 75    |  
| op1       | NULL     | stem3  | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |  
| op1       | set2     | stem1  | cat5     | pattern3 | 85    |  
| op1       | set2     | stem3  | cat2     | pattern4 | 46    |  
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

I am trying to create a view that returns rows grouped by `operation` and `stem` and with the lowest start value in the group and also with the category and pattern for the row with that start value. For the case above where the first two rows have the same start value, I don't care which row is returned. The result must also include any rows with null values as in the fifth row.  There is a separate view for each rule set.

So the desiredd result for rule set `set1`

```
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+  
| operation | rule_set |  stem  | category | pattern  | start |  
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+  
| op1       | set1     | stem1  | cat1     | pattern1 | 100   |  
| op1       | set1     | stem2  | cat3     | pattern2 | 75    |  
| op1       | NULL     | stem3  | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |  
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

The closest I've gotten so far is with the following SQL

```
SELECT [dbo].[Table].[operation],
       [dbo].[Table].[rule_set],
       [dbo].[Table].[stem],
       [dbo].[Table].[category],
       [dbo].[Table].[pattern],
       [dbo].[Table].[start]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        [operation], [rule_set], [stem], MIN(start) AS first
    FROM [dbo].[Table]
    WHERE [dbo].[Table].[rule_set] = 'set1'
    GROUP BY [operation], [rule_set], [stem]
    ) temp
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table]
ON
    [temp].[operation] = [dbo].[Table].[operation] AND
    [temp].[rule_set] = [dbo].[Table].[rule_set] AND
    [temp].[stem] = [dbo].[Table].[stem] AND
    [temp].[first] = [dbo].[Table].[start]
```

But the above SQL fails to meet my requirements in two respects:

- it returns two rows (with start value 100) for `stem1` whereas it should pick one of the two rows
- it does not include the row with the nulls.
  That is, the actual result is as follows:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+  
| operation | rule_set |  stem  | category | pattern  | start |  
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+  
| op1       | set1     | stem1  | cat1     | pattern1 | 100   |  
| op1       | set1     | stem1  | cat1     | pattern2 | 100   |  
| op1       | set1     | stem2  | cat3     | pattern2 | 75    |  
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

How should I change the above SQL code to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by rule_set, stem order by start) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where start is null or seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I'm not sure how to apply your answer to my situation. I tried `select *
from (select [dbo].[Table].*,
             row_number() over (partition by rule_set, stem order by start) as seqnum
      from [dbo].[Table]
     ) t
where start is null or start = 1;` That returns only the row with the nulls and adds a seqnum column (which I don't need).

Comment: I think I figured it out. In the last line it should be `seqnum = 1` instead of `start = 1`

Comment: And, if I don't want the seqnum column, I just need to list the columns explicitly on the first line.

Comment: @mark.sack . . . `select` the columns that you do want.  I use `select *` in answers because the selection list is usually not important to the logic being shown.